# Searching for a number in a database column where column contains series of numbers seperated by a delimeter '"&" in SQLite

Tags: sql, regex, sqlite

My table structure is as follows :

```
id category 

1   1&2&3

2   18&2&1

3   11

4   1&11

5   3&1

6   1
```

**My Question:** I need a sql query which generates the result set as follows when the user searched category is 1

```
id category

1   1&2&3

2   18&2&1

4   1&11

5   3&1

6   1
```

but i am getting all the results not the expected one

I have tried regexp and like operators but no success.

```
select * from mytable where category like '%1%'

select * from mytable where category regexp  '([.]*)(1)(.*)'
```

I really dont know about regexp I just found it.

so please help me out.

Comment: Note that `REGEXP` is not defined by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For matching a list item separated by `&`, use:

```
 SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE '&'||category||'&' LIKE '%&1&%';
```

this will match entire item (ie, only `1`, not `11`, ...), whether it is at list beginning, middle or end.

Comment: @CL. Ups... I copied from a previous answer and didn't notice `NOT` part!